# jQuery and data attributes

Tags: jquery

In what case, this code would return 0?

```
$(this).parent().data("id")
```

And this code, would return the real value?

```
$(this).parent().attr("data-id")
```

Thanks.

Comment: somebody has assigned a value `$(this).parent().data("id", 0)`

Comment: jQuery data() and data- attributes are separate things. jQuery uses its own cache while data- is a native HTML5 feature.

Comment: @Virus721 you can fetch `data-*` attributes using `data()`...

Comment: @brbcoding It fetches that data if and only if no data is found in jquery cache.

Answer (score 4):

If `.data("id")` and `.attr("data-id")` are returning different values, then either the value of data property `id` has been updated via the jQuery `data()` function or the `data-id` attribute value has been updated since the first call to `.data("id")`.

The jQuery `data()` function will use the `data-` attributes of an element to initialize the value of that data property. However, changes to the data property are not reflected in the HTML. So updating a value using `data()` does *not* also update the attribute.

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5):

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is
>   accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values
>   are then stored internally in jQuery).

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv" data-id="realValue"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#myDiv').data('id'); //returns 'realValue'
$('#myDiv').data('id', 0);
$('#myDiv').data('id'); //returns 0
$('#myDiv').attr('data-id'); //returns 'realValue'
```